# How to import a spring application context into another application context?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I have two spring application contexts. One is local to my application and the other is from one of the maven dependencies.

Now, my **applicationContext.xml** file look like this.

```
<import resource="classpath*:**/sample-applicationContext.xml" />
```

and I have `<context:component-scan>` in the `sample-applicationContext.xml` file which scans for components.

and Now, when I do the following..

```
ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
MyClass m=ctx.getBean(MyClass.class);
```

Unfortunately, when I get the `MyClass` object, the object is created however, I see that dependencies in `MyClass` are not injected.

The dependencies autowired in `MyClass` are the beans that are scanned using the `<context:component-scan>` in `sample-applicationContext.xml` file.

Is there any way to make use of multiple application contexts present in the Maven dependencies and autowire beans in them in my project classes?

Comment: Hey check out other similar question with answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468195/spring-import-application-context-from-another-project)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about maven dependencies, but you are trying to do something like a cross-context using spring. Take a look at this link: http://blog.imaginea.com/cross-context-communication-between-web-applications/

EDIT: it seems there is a way, take a look at this post: [Loading spring application context files that are inside a jar in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303242/loading-spring-application-context-files-that-are-inside-a-jar-in-classpath)

Comment: that didn't work. I am getting the dependency bean object, when I call them using ApplicationContext object `ctx.getBean(MyDependencyBean.class)` but when autowiring `MyDependencyBean` in `MyClass`. It is not autowired. In `MyClass` the `MyDependencyBean` is made `transient` to avoid `NotSerializableException`. Is it the reason why the dependency is not autowired:? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

the following way, you can load the multiple spring applicationContext files.

```
ApplicationContext context = 
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"sample-applicationContext.xml",   "applicationContext.xml"});
```

it will be good if you can post the applicationContext.xml , sample-applicationContext.xml and MyClass code segments here.