# How to load application context of a Spring jar present in Maven Project library

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jar

I have a standalone spring project which is working fine. While running the project I simply load the application context in the main method like:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
SampleBean sampleBean = (SampleBean) context.getBean("sampleBean");
```

and things get moving.

Now I have to create a jar file for this project and include it in another Maven project which is not a Spring project. Here, I have to call the functions present in the included Spring jar file using classes which in itself contain autowiring.

Now since I am directly calling the Class function without loading the application context, other dependencies of autowiring are failing.

Please suggest how do I load the application context of the included Spring jar.

Comment: Possible Duplicate -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303242/loading-spring-application-context-files-that-are-inside-a-jar-in-classpath

Comment: This link talks about how to include and load Spring jar in another Spring application. So in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6304113/1184527 says that a program A which is a Spring application is added into another program B (which again has the Spring dependencies). The dependency is updated in Program B's pom.xml and the application context.xml is loaded from program B's main method.

Answer (score 0):

You can load them in your `web.xml` file like

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value> 
            classpath:application-context.xml.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

and then you can use them in your code like normal way using @ Annotation.

---

There is one more way but I haven't tested it yet.

```
  <import resource="classpath:/application-context.xml"/>
```

Comment: I have a standalone application and as such there is no web.xml